# How to resolve 'Undefined variable" in Kinesis example script?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-kinesis

I am 100% new to Python and grabbing examples from the web to learn while following the **Python 3.6.2** Documentation.

I have a script from here that I am trying to make work:

[Getting Started with AWS Kinesis and Python](http://www.arundhaj.com/blog/getting-started-kinesis-python.html)

My PyDev IDE says "Undefined variable: response" Line 10 of script below:

1.)  Being new to Python, I cannot understand what language construct is used here?  It looks like a multi-dimensional array (coming from a Java background that is..)

**response['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId']**

2.) How do I resolve making it no longer "Undefined"?

## SCRIPT:

```
import boto3
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time

my_stream_name = 'python-stream'

kinesis_client = boto3.client('kinesis', region_name='us-east-1')

my_shard_id = response['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId']

shard_iterator = kinesis_client.get_shard_iterator(StreamName=my_stream_name,
                                                      ShardId=my_shard_id,
                                                      ShardIteratorType='LATEST')

my_shard_iterator = shard_iterator['ShardIterator']

record_response = kinesis_client.get_records(ShardIterator=my_shard_iterator,
                                              Limit=2)

while 'NextShardIterator' in record_response:
    record_response = kinesis_client.get_records(ShardIterator=record_response['NextShardIterator'],
                                                  Limit=2)

    print record_response

    # wait for 5 seconds
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, your `response` variable is not assigned any value anywhere. Based on your example `response` variable holds the response of your stream description.

I recommend python REPL to get started,

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr  4 2017, 08:46:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> import json

>>> boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name="aws-federated") //using credentials localted in ~/.aws/credentials
>>> client = boto3.client('kinesis', region_name='us-west-2') //I use west regiion, you can change to east as in your question
```

I have a stream named `gregor-samsa-2`,

```
>>> client.list_streams(Limit=100)
{u'StreamNames': [u'gregor-samsa-1', u'gregor-samsa-2', u'HasMoreStreams': False, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'ed632ba9-8bba-3173-bc93-5b04547d1f2a', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'ed632ba9-8bba-3173-bc93-5b04547d1f2a', 'content-length': '244', 'x-amz-id-2': 'NJpwLfREWneUwQHIYrS+L9EmUwTUyywMLUWNzNK53C1GIKRZx8/z2TiMe9+oY3eOblNxYleMkEHPCP7D7An3Clw4EII+Tn5M', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'date': 'Mon, 24 Jul 2017 22:02:20 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}}}

>>> response = client.describe_stream( StreamName='gregor-samsa-2')
```

If you print response, its a hashmap/ or in python's terms its `Dictionary`.

```
>>> response
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'f4130cb3-6ffb-aebe-a5e3-7e831eeea949', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'f4130cb3-6ffb-aebe-a5e3-7e831eeea949', 'content-length': '841', 'x-amz-id-2': 'O0qfcRJcv9NrNlPc+DmjMPl4Fa9LKl/3D4dxzD+BQTnkisAlL3chw8P5GGZFcUSmHi+WaDBSWcNvcGuHQcfivJN2EBN7nPig', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'date': 'Mon, 24 Jul 2017 22:08:47 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}}, u'StreamDescription': {u'HasMoreShards': False, u'RetentionPeriodHours': 24, u'StreamName': u'gregor-samsa-2', u'Shards': [{u'ShardId': u'shardId-000000000000', u'HashKeyRange': {u'EndingHashKey': u'170141183460469231731687303715884105727', u'StartingHashKey': u'0'}, u'SequenceNumberRange': {u'StartingSequenceNumber': u'49574403640320687182855826859993394354817752107006820354'}}, {u'ShardId': u'shardId-000000000001', u'HashKeyRange': {u'EndingHashKey': u'340282366920938463463374607431768211455', u'StartingHashKey': u'170141183460469231731687303715884105728'}, u'SequenceNumberRange': {u'StartingSequenceNumber': u'49574403640342987928054357483134930073090400468512800786'}}], u'StreamARN': u'arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:033814027302:stream/gregor-samsa-2', u'EnhancedMonitoring': [{u'ShardLevelMetrics': []}], u'StreamCreationTimestamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 0, 51, 53, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'StreamStatus': u'ACTIVE'}}

>>> print(type(response))
<type 'dict'>
```

To get the partition you want to query on, access the response hashmap as you are doing in your example, (using `dictionary['key1']['key2']`)

`response['StreamDescription']['Shards']` gives an array.

```
>>> print(type(response['StreamDescription']['Shards']))
<type 'list'>
```

you can access list with `list[index]` pattern.

```
>>> response['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId']
u'shardId-000000000000'
```

exit python REPL,

```
>>> exit()
```

Comment: yes, i see now.  Adding this line at Line 9 resolves the issue.  So, much for using other peoples examples to learn.  I definitely learned!!           
 response = kinesis_client.describe_stream(StreamName = my_stream_name)

Comment: Cool, you made it work. Strange, the tutorial you are following does not have response defined.